# Adjust screen brightness, contrast, and gamma

Tags: c#, screen-brightness

I'm a beginner in C# and to practice I'm building tools that are useful to me. Now, I want to build an application that can adjust screen brightness, contrast, and gamma. Something similar to Darkfix.

[image: Darkfix screenshot]

I have searched for something to get me started but couldn't find anything useful. How can I adjust these screen properties?

Comment: I deleted my answer because apparently links aren't allowed, even if the address the problem. Sorry.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 including links in an answer is fine. All you have to do is edit the answer to include some more explanation/code/whatever. theres no need to go to my post history and take it personally

Comment: @psoshmo pretty sure I've not done anything different though. So why is my answer a 'no no' as you put it? I used your history to prove that link only answers are ubiquitous. And yes, if you are unfairly singling me out then i will take it personally.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 Link-only answers are discussed in meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/65277/are-link-only-answers-poor-practice and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/72000/should-there-be-a-policy-about-one-link-only-answers although linking to SO itself isn't as bad I don't think.

Comment: That first meta link seems to suggest that link only answers can be good (and might be improved by adding a summary to the SO answer), but not considered top quality. I agree. However, in this case i was merely coping a few bookmarks the OP might find useful.

Comment: @3-14159265358979323846264 I was in no way trying to single you out, and sorry if I somehow came off that way.

Comment: Apology accepted. I apologise for post-stalking you ... it's just the first time I have witnessed someone complaining about link only answers! :o)

Comment: tis all good my friend. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer     thats the meta thread that I think many people consider to be the authority on the issue. Its also an interesting read and pretty funny

Comment: @psoshmo Ok. That's a good read. I still think there's a bit of apple in my answer as i only just posted the links so i know they're working, but like most apples i expect it to decompose. Hopefully someone with their own, fresh ingredients will provide a full on apple pie before that happens.